# Unzip error, is recovery possible?

Tags: zip, compression, corruption

I compressed 4 separate folders with some wedding videos (!!) a few months ago. Today I tried to unzip them, and had no problem with the last 2, but the first 2 of them show an error:

```
   carmensandoval$ unzip AlineJoseLuisVideoCabina_Folder1.zip

   Archive:  AlineJoseLuisVideoCabina_Folder1.zip
   End-of-central-directory signature not found.  Either this file is not
   a zipfile, or it constitutes one disk of a multi-part archive.  In the
   latter case the central directory and zipfile comment will be found on
   the last disk(s) of this archive.
   unzip:  cannot find zipfile directory in one of AlineJoseLuisVideoCabina_Folder1.zip    
   or AlineJoseLuisVideoCabina_Folder1.zip.zip, and cannot find   
   AlineJoseLuisVideoCabina_Folder1.zip.ZIP, period.
```

As someone else suggested in another similar post, I checked if my files were indeed ZIP files, and they are:

```
file AlineJoseLuisVideoCabina_Folder1.zip 
AlineJoseLuisVideoCabina_Folder1.zip: Zip archive data, at least v1.0 to extract
```

I suspect that these 2 folders were corrupted when uploading them to send them to a client (they took a while and the connection was interrupted a few times, does this even matter?)
Is there any way to try and get back at least some of what was inside?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first thing to do is make a copy of the file, to make sure it can be read properly e.g to a file called `xx.zip`, and determine its length:

```
 cp AlineJoseLuisVideoCabina_Folder1.zip xx.zip
 ls -l xx.zip
```

You have the size of any photo from the extracted other zip files, and since you cannot compress photos that much inside a zip file you can calculate if the amount of photos you expect could fit in that archive.

After that assuming the file is big enough to contain anything that might be recoverable, use:

```
 zip -FF xx.zip --out yy.zip
```

to try and recover the zip file (that is the `zip` command, not `unzip`).

Comment: @Amphiteóth Thanks for catching that. It cannot harm if there is something there it might find the entries. But if the zip is truncated there is little hope, hence the recommendation to make an estimate of how much might be there. Little hope of finding 100 pictures in a 1K zip.

Comment: Thank you very much! All of the videos were intact; who knows what happened? You saved me big time :)

Comment: thank you I got nearly all my files back - this is good enough for me

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways as you can try :

Firstly make a copy of zip file you think having a problem and play with copied zip file.

Try :

> As the error suggest, the file ( AlineJoseLuisVideoCabina_Folder1.zip.zip )contains two extensions at the end. Remove .zip extension from the end of the file, that solved my case while extracting compressed files.

If it doesn't work in your case, try
    `jar xvf AlineJoseLuisVideoCabina_Folder1.zip`
OR
    `zip -F AlineJoseLuisVideoCabina_Folder1.zip -O AlineJoseLuisVideoCabina_Folder1-new.zip`
and try extracting from latter zip file.